# Pull data from another workbook with condition

Tags: vba, excel, pull

I'm trying to pull data from workbook1 into workbook2 which satisfied certain condition from workbook1. Below is my code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim iLast As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim targetlastrow As Long, sourcelstrow As Long
Dim Sourcelastcol As Long
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim xCol As Integer

Set source = Workbooks("workbook1").Sheets(1)
Set target = Workbooks("workbook2").Sheets("Sheet1")
xRow = 10
Set InputRng = source.Range("F2:F" & 41)
Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)

xCol = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        iRow = i Mod xRow
        iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
        xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

This is sample output workbook2

[image]

Sample data from workbook1

[image]

Currently I managed to pull all first 40 data from workbook1:Column F. But I'm trying to pull the first 40 data with only PASS condition. Refer to Workbook1 column C.

Please help. I'm new using this vba.

Comment: Tried adding a command to delete the data you don't need? It might save you some coding time, it won't execute as fast though

Comment: That solution also can. But I must do that way without editing source file. @LJ01

Comment: Would something like this for the last statement in the For...Next loop work?  If xValue = "PASS" Then xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue

Comment: I have tried but didn't work. thank you.

Comment: I was thinking removing spare stuff after you copy it to your new sheet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim iLast As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim targetlastrow As Long, sourcelstrow As Long
Dim Sourcelastcol As Long
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim ConRng As Range
Dim xCol As Integer

Set source = Workbooks("workbook1").Sheets(1)
Set target = Workbooks("workbook2").Sheets("Sheet1")
xRow = 10
Set InputRng = source.Range("F2:F" & 41)
Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
Set ConRng = source.Range("C2:C" & 41)
Set ConRng = ConRng.Columns(1)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
k = 0
xCol = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        xCon = ConRng.Cells(i + 1)
        If xCon = "PASS" Then
            iRow = k Mod xRow
            iCol = VBA.Int(k / xRow)
            xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
        Else
            k = k - 1
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your query. But after the condition is "FAIL" and xValue is 1.654,  It pop out error "Subscript out of range"      xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue